# Show that $d(∗df) = (∆f)dx ∧ dy ∧ dz$

Tags: differential-forms

I'm having this problem and I have no idea how to figure it out.

In $\mathbb{R}^3$, we denote a linear operator $*$ : $Ω^1$($\mathbb{R}^3$) → $Ω^2$($\mathbb{R}^3$) defined by:

$∗dx = dy ∧ dz$ ,
  $ ∗dy = dz ∧ dx,$
     $∗dz = dx ∧ dy$

a) If $f$:$\mathbb{R}^3$→$\mathbb{R}$ is a smooth function, show that $d(∗df) = (∆f)dx ∧ dy ∧ dz$, 
where $∆f=∇ · ∇f$ is the Laplace operator of $f$.

b) Using Stokes Theorem, calculate $\int_s$ $\omega$

if $\omega$=$*df$

with $f=(x-y+2z)^2$ 
and $S$ an ellipsoid of equation $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}=1$ oriented in a way such that its orientation is compatible with its domain of $\mathbb{R}^3$

I would be grateful to anyone who has some ideas, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Here are some hints and ideas.  For both parts (a) and (b), you should use the formula $$df = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} dy + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} dx$$
For part (a): You should try to evaluate $d(\ast df)$.  First find $df$, then $\ast df$, then $d(\ast df)$. Hopefully the result will be $\Delta f \,dx \wedge dy \wedge dz$.

For part (b): You should draw the given ellipsoid $S$, and ask yourself whether you can think of $S$ as the boundary surface of some solid $E$.  Then Stokes' Theorem will give you
$$\int_S \omega = \int_{\partial E} \ast df = \int_E d(\ast df).$$
Part (a) gives you a nice formula for $d(\ast df)$, which should help in evaluating the integral.